# How do I use a short[] to a BinaryWriter?

Tags: c#, arrays, file, short

```
short[] sArray = new short[100];
```

Many 16-bit data in sArray[100], So I want to write using BinaryWriter class.

But BinaryWriter has write(byte[]) and write(char[]) only.

How to write 16-bit(short[]) data to the file?

Answer (score 3):

You need to write each value individually using the [BinaryWriter.Write(short) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/091b1s67.aspx).

*Writing:*

```
binaryWriter.Write(sArray.Length); // BinaryWriter.Write(Int32) overload
for (int i = 0; i < sArray.Length; i++)
{
    binaryWriter.Write(sArray[i]); // BinaryWriter.Write(Int16) overload
}
```

*Reading:*

```
short[] result = new short[binaryReader.ReadInt32()];
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    result[i] = binaryReader.ReadInt16();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Answer.
But Writing: for(int i=0; i<sArray.length; i++) { binaryWriter.Write(sArray[i]) }
sArray[i] -> Compile Error : Overload is wrong..
sArray[i] data is short data...